# Why Spring MVC does not allow to expose Model or BindingResult to an @ExceptionHandler?

Tags: spring-mvc, exception

### Situation

I'm trying to group the code that logs the exceptions and render a nice view in a few methods. At the moment the logic is sometime in the `@RequestHandler` itself (in the a *catch* block), othertimes is delegated to an utility class (that works but moves the logic away from the place where the exception is thrown).

Spring's `@ExceptionHandler` seemed the way to group everything in one place (the controller itself or a parent) and get rid of some code (no need to put logic in the *try-catch* and no need for an utility class)... until I realized that an `@ExceptionHandler` methods won't have the `ModelMap` or `BindingResult` parameters autowired. Currently those objects are used to render the view with a sensible error message and we want to log some information contained in these objects as well.

### Question

Why Spring doesn't not support method arguments such `ModelMap` or `BindingResult` for the `@ExceptionHandler`? What is the rationale behind it?

### Possible solution

In the Spring source code (3.0.5) the arguments for the method are resolved in the `HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod`. A an exception thrown by the request handler is caught there and re-thrown. The `@ExceptionHandler` and it's parameters are resolved elsewhere. As a workaround I thought to check if the Exception implements an hypothetical  "ModelAware" or "BindingResultAware" interface, and in that case set Model and BindingResult attributes before re-throwhing it.
How does it sound?

Answer (score 5):

As stated before you can raise an exception wrapping a binding result object in some method of your controller:

```
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        logBindingErrors(bindingResult);
        //return "users/create";
        // Exception handling happens later in this controller
        throw new BindingErrorsException("MVC binding errors", userForm, bindingResult);
    }
```

With your exception defined as illustrated here:

```
public class BindingErrorsException extends RuntimeException {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BindingErrorsException.class); 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7882202987868263849L;

    private final UserForm userForm;
    private final BindingResult bindingResult;

    public BindingErrorsException(
        final String message, 
        final UserForm userForm, 
        final BindingResult bindingResult
    ) {
        super(message);
        this.userForm = userForm;
        this.bindingResult = bindingResult;

        log.error(getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    public UserForm getUserForm() {
        return userForm;
    }

    public BindingResult getBindingResult() {
        return bindingResult;
    }
}
```

Next you just have to extract the required information from the raised then caught exception. Here assuming you have a suitable exception handler defined on your controller. It might be in a controller advice instead or even elewhere. See the Spring documentation for suitable and appropriate locations.

```
@ExceptionHandler(BindingErrorsException.class)
public ModelAndView bindingErrors(
    final HttpServletResponse resp, 
    final Exception ex
) {
    if(ex instanceof BindingErrorsException) {
        final BindingErrorsException bex = (BindingErrorsException) ex;
        final ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("users/create", bex.getBindingResult().getModel());
        mav.addObject("user", bex.getUserForm());
        return mav;
    } else {
        final ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("users/create");
        return mav;            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into to same problem a while ago. The `ModelMap` or `BindingResult` are explicitly not listed as supported argument types in the JavaDocs of `@ExceptionHandler`, so this must have been intentional.

I reckon the reason behind it being that throwing exceptions in general could leave your `ModelMap` in an inconsistent state. So depending on your situation you might consider

- Explicitly catch the exception to tell Spring MVC that you know what you're doing (you could use the Template pattern to refactor exception handling logic into one single place)
- If you're in control of the exception hierarchy you could hand over the `BindingResult` to the exception and extract it from the exception later for rendering purposes
- Not throw an exception in the first place, but use some result code (just like `BeanValidation` does for example)

HTH

Answer (score 2):

To improve the first answer:

```
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {MethodArgumentNotValidException.class})
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ResponseBody
public VndErrors methodArgumentNotValidException(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, WebRequest request) {
    List<FieldError> fieldErrors = ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors();
    List<ObjectError> globalErrors = ex.getBindingResult().getGlobalErrors();
    List<VndError> errors = new ArrayList<>(fieldErrors.size() + globalErrors.size());
    VndError error;
    for (FieldError fieldError : fieldErrors) {
        error = new VndError(ErrorType.FORM_VALIDATION_ERROR.toString(), fieldError.getField() + ", "
                + fieldError.getDefaultMessage());
        errors.add(error);
    }
    for (ObjectError objectError : globalErrors) {
        error = new VndError(ErrorType.FORM_VALIDATION_ERROR.toString(),  objectError.getDefaultMessage());
        errors.add(error);
    }
    return new VndErrors(errors);
}
```

There is already MethodArgumentNotValidException has already a BindingResult object, and you can use it, if you don't need to create an specific exception for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem to "add" FunctinalException to ourthe BindingResult

To resolve it, we use aop, if the controller method throws a runtime exception (or the one you want), 
the aop catch it and update the bindingresult or model (if they are args of the method).

The method has to be annoted with a specific annotation containing the error path (configurable for specific exception if necessary).

It is not the best way because developer must not forget to add args that he don't use in its method but Spring does not provide a simple system to do this need.

Answer (score 0):

I've wondered this too.

In order to handle bean validation in a way that allows for a non-global error view to display any `ConstraintViolationException`s that may be thrown, I opted for a solution along the lines of what @Stefan Haberl proposed:

> Explicitly catch the exception to tell Spring MVC that you know what you're doing (you could use the Template pattern to refactor exception handling logic into one single place)

I created a simple `Action` interface:

```
public interface Action {
  String run();
}
```

And an `ActionRunner` class which does the work of ensuring `ConstraintViolationException`s are handled nicely (basically the messages from each `ConstraintViolationException` is simply added to a `Set` and added to the model):

```
public class ActionRunner {
  public String handleExceptions(Model model, String input, Action action) {
    try {
      return action.run();
    }
    catch (RuntimeException rEx) {
      Set<String> errors = BeanValidationUtils.getErrorMessagesIfPresent(rEx);
      if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        model.addAttribute("errors", errors);
        return input;
      }
      throw rEx;
    }
  }
}
```

Java 8 makes this pretty nice to run within the controller action method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/event/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveEvent(Event event, Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
  return new ActionRunner().handleExceptions(model, "event/form", () -> {
    eventRepository.save(event);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("messages", "Event saved.");
    return "redirect:/events";
  });
}
```

This is to wrap up those action methods for which I'd like to explicitly handle exceptions that could be thrown due to Bean Validation.  I still have a global `@ExceptionHandler` but this deals with only "oh crap" exceptions.

Answer (score -1):

Actually it does, just create an `@ExceptionHandler` method for `MethodArgumentNotValidException`.

That class gives you access to a `BindingResult` object.