# How to use Exceptionhandler annotation after handling binding result annoation

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have defined a controller class which validates using jsr annotation (@valid) and im handling its exception via bindingresult object but i wish to take it to the next level and configure the controller class to handle contraintviolation exception how to cofigure that for the same controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveOrUpdatelawyers", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody  Map<String,Object> getSaved(@Valid Lawyers lawyers,BindingResult result){
    Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();

    Object obj=new Object();
        if(result.hasErrors())
        {  
            for (Object object : result.getAllErrors()) {
                if(object instanceof FieldError) {
                    FieldError fieldError = (FieldError) object;

                 obj= (fieldError.getDefaultMessage());
                }
            map.put("status","400");
            map.put("message",obj);
            return map;
        }}

        lawyerServices.saveOrUpdatelawyers(lawyers);
        map.put("status","200");
        map.put("message","Your record have been saved successfully");
        return map;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a Custom BindingErrorsException that extends Runtime Exception and put your logic there.

Then you must have a @ControllerAdvice class that have different @ExceptionHandler.

I do have a sample project that might get you started : https://github.com/dhananjay12/learning-spring-rest/blob/master/error-handling/src/main/java/com/djcodes/spring/rest/errorhandling/EmployeeController.java

You can also have a look at this answer - [Why Spring MVC does not allow to expose Model or BindingResult to an @ExceptionHandler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799393/why-spring-mvc-does-not-allow-to-expose-model-or-bindingresult-to-an-exceptionh)